# eslint: disable warning - `defined but never used` for specific function?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have this function:

```
function render(){
    // Do stuff
}
```

I do not call that function, because it is called from HTML as an event function, like:

```
<textarea id="input" class="input-box" onkeyup="render()"></textarea>
```

Well, ESLint does not see that, so it gives that warning (`render` is defined, but never used). Is there a way to specify that function is called elsewhere? Or just mute the warning?

For example, if a global variable is used, I can do `/* global SomeVar*/` and it will mute the warning of a not-defined variable. Maybe something similar could be done on functions like in the example?

Comment: That is one reason why you should avoid to to use inline event handlers and should use `addEventListener('keyup', render, false)` instead. Using inline event handlers will also result in problems if you use scripts like uglifyjs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Provide a [config comment](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) telling it to ignore that rule (*defined but never used* is the `no-unused-vars` rule)

```
function render() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    // do stuff
    var x; // still raises defined but never used
}
```

Comment: I have a comment at the top of my JS for something else `/* global Swiper:readonly */` ...is there a way to work this sort of fix into that? I'd having the issue with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { script here });`

Answer (score 19):

Just put this rule in the *.eslintrc.js* file, and please don't forget to restart the server...

```
module.exports = {
      rules: {
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
      },
    }
```

Comment: the question specifies 'for specific functions'

Comment: You are right @johnktejik after the question is updated to a specific function this answer will still work only if someone wants to disable it for all methods...

Answer (score 13):

If you *don’t* want to change the code:

ESLint provides both a way to disable, both to enable the linting via **comments**. You only added before functions `/* eslint-disable */`  and after functions `/* eslint-enable */`

**Example**

```
/* eslint-disable */ // <-- Before function

function render(){
   // Do stuff
}

/* eslint-enable */  // <-- After function
```

[More information](https://brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-disable-eslint-rule-via-javascript-comment/).

Comment: While this technically works, the answer from Alex K. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399923/eslint-disable-warning-defined-but-never-used-for-specific-function/45400071#45400071) is more efficient as it targets the specific line where the unused variable is defined.

Answer (score 8):

You can use an [`exported` comment block](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#exported) for this, such as:

```
/* exported render */
```

This tells ESLint that it is okay for the declaration be unused, which is more semantically correct than just silencing the warning. It might also work with certain other tools such as [minifiers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minification#Noun), but that is purely conjecture on my part.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and is a great solution in my own case, where I am gradually splitting apart a large existing JS file.

Comment: This is the best / proper solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `argsIgnorePattern` option. It specifies exceptions not to check for.

Usage: arguments whose names match a regexp pattern. For example, variables whose names begin with an underscore.

```
/* eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
   @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars: [1, { vars: 'all', 'argsIgnorePattern': '^_' }] */


function foo(x, _y) {
    return x + 1;
}
foo();
```

Please check on *[no-unused-vars, Options](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#options)*.

Comment: This is super useful! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

ESLint has a `caughtErrors` option which is used to catch block arguments validation and can have each of below values:

1. `none` (default) in order to avoid checking these errors.
2. `all`

So you can simply ignore not-used errors by changing this option. Here's a general example:

```
eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "caughtErrors": "none" }]
```

Comment: if you are using a config file, you can use `"rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 0
    },`

Answer (score 3):

Pretty similar to what [Alex K. is proposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399923/eslint-disable-warning-defined-but-never-used-for-specific-function/51295375#51295375), there is also `eslint-disable-next-line`. I generally prefer that to not make the method definition line of code too long. You can use it like this:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
function render(){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to explicitly state that the function is available within the global scope. This will stop the warning from firing.

```js
function getUser() {...} // Won't throw
function getData() {...} // Will throw
window.getUser = getUser
```